# Is it possible to detect change through traversal?

Tags: jquery, traversal

Is it possible to detect change through traversal?

e.g.

```
<div id="s2id_region">
  <a>
    <span>Buckinghamshire</span>
  <input type="text"role="button">
</div>
```

Can you in some way detect change in `<span>Buckinghamshire</span>` through traversal on `id="s2id_region"`.

I know its a bit strange to want to do it like this, but this plugin that I use kinda sets it up that the only unique item/id is two element up from the changing value (Buckinhamshire) in this case.

Comment: onDOMSubTreeModified ????

Comment: MutationEvent. http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the `DOMSubtreeModified` event which will trigger whenever the DOM structure changes.

```
$('#s2id_region span').on('DOMSubtreeModified ', function(){
    alert('change')
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/te7h3ohj/)